# signatures for autodesk checklist

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-bim360

Doe's anyone know how to get the signatures for a checklist in the response from a checklist?

I'm making a request to the following endpoint and was hoping to see a "Section_item" for the signatures, however, this data is not being returned in the response body.

`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/checklists/v1/containers/:containerId/instances/:ChecklistId?include=,sections.items,sections.items.attachment`s

Is there a separate endpoint I need to hit to get the Signature information for a given check one that includes the urn for the image of the checklist would be highly useful?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this data of signature has not been exposed by API. Current API (GET Instance) only tells it is signed or not, but does not tell who signed and the image. 
We have had a wish at #SCCOM-7650.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang That is a pity that it's not available Thank you for answering my question.